# Revert change with Knockoutjs and bindingHandlers using computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let's say I have something like `<input type="text" data-bind="format: quantity">`, that uses an custom `bindingHandlers` called `format` defined like this:

```
var getElementValue = function($element) {
  return $element.val().replace(/\$/g, '');
};

ko.bindingHandlers.format = {
  init: function(element, bindingAccessor) {
    var $element = $(element),
      bindings = bindingAccessor();

    $element.val('$' + ko.unwrap(bindings));

    $element.change(function () {
      bindings(getElementValue($element));
    });
  },
  update: function(element, bindingAccessor) {
    var $element = $(element),
      bindings = bindingAccessor();
  $element.val('$' + ko.unwrap(bindings));
  }
};
```

And a view model like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self._quantity = ko.observable(0);
  self.quantity = ko.computed({
    read: self._quantity,
    write: function(newValue) {
      if (newValue < 0) {
        self._quantity.valueHasMutated();
        console.log('quantity is invalid');
        return;
      }
      self._quantity(newValue);
    }
    });
}
```

Since negative quantity is not allowed, the idea would be to revert the input to it previous value if that is provided.

However, the `self._quantity.valueHasMutated();` in the `write` function is not notifying the `bindingHandlers` `update` of a mutation.

Any ideas? I have a [JSFiddle setup for more details](http://jsfiddle.net/tt7yrote/5/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to tell knockout to react to changes also when the old value and the new value are the same, by using `.extend({ notify: 'always' })` for both, the "backup" observable, and the computed to reflect the changes in the text input:

```
  self._quantity = ko.observable(0).extend({ notify: 'always' });
  self.quantity = ko.computed({
    read: self._quantity,
    write: function(newValue) {
      if (newValue < 0) {
        self._quantity(self._quantity.peek());
        //self._quantity.valueHasMutated();
        console.log('quantity is invalid');
        return;
      }
      self._quantity(newValue);
    }
  }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k0deqt8x/

**EDIT:**

BTW, this solution also works when using `ko.options.deferUpdates = true;`

Alternatively, you cold use a more standard solution like the one created by rniemeyer here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

Comment: It worked with `valueHasMutated` by adding the `extend({ notify: 'always' })` to both like you said. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure *why exactly* your code doesn't work, but I did try some stuff and came up with something that does...

Since your input is bound to `quantity`, it'd make sense to send out a message that this value changed. You can do so by calling `notifySubscribers` on the computed:

```
self.quantity.notifySubscribers(self.quantity.peek());
```

This still does feel a bit strange, and I'd suggest looking into an extender like the ones in [these examples](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pxxnuu2z/